# ¿Cómo hago para que la suma de un array me return 10 sin modificar el array inicial?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Realice el siguiente código donde me devuelve la suma de un array y suma dá como resultado 16. Ahora necesito que la suma del array me return 10. El array solo debe modificarse dentro de la función no en el array inicial.

```
function sumOfTen(arr){
  return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}

console.log(sumOfTen([2,5,1,5,2,1]));
```

Comment: [2,5,1,5,2,1].reduce( (a,b)=> a+b) Podrias simplificarlo asi. Una cosa mas, el metodo reduce no modifica de ninguna manera el array, en cambio devuelve solo un entero, que en este caso es la suma

Comment: A qué te referís a que te devuelva `10` la suma del array? Por lo que veo, pasando `[2,5,1,5,2,1]` suma un total de `16`.

Comment: @SoniaToledo realmente no entiendo tu comentario, ¿podrías explicarme?

Comment: @Kleith si, el array devuelve 16 , ahora necesito que devuelva 10 sin modificar el array inicial.

Comment: Quiero decir, que en vez de crear una funcion que reciba el array, puedes llamar directamente a "reduce" sobre el array, pues "reduce" es un metodo de arrays. Y como pregunto el usuario anterior, porque debe devolver 10? Porque he visto, y sale 16

Comment: @Kleith te dice algo cierto la suma no es 10 , cuando ejecutas esa funcion el te devuelve otro array/valor

Comment: @Kleith sé que la suma del array no devuelve 10 sino 16. Necesito que devuelva 10 como lo mencione en mi pregunta. :)

Comment: Y cuál es la lógica que debe seguir para que devuelva como resultado 10?

Comment: [2,5,1,5,2,1].reduce( function(anterior, ele){  if(anterior>10){ return 10; }else{ if(anterior==10){ return anterior; }else{ return anterior+ele;}  }     }     ,   0)
No le encuentro mucho sentido al ejercicio, pero esto da 10. Acaso quieres un arreglo nuevo cuyos valores sean los que sumen 10?

Comment: je me recuerda cierta función `function calcularDigitoVerificador(n){return 8;}` que en este caso sería `function sumOfTen(arr){return 10}` debe haber algo de información que falta

Answer (score 1):

No tendría sentido restarle un 6 a la fórmula, ya que eso sería como acomodar el resultado jugando con los números. Esta no sería una práctica útil para el aprendizaje.

Yo lo que creo, es que la idea de tu profesor era que consultaras acerca de la función en sí y pudieras conocer los parámetros adicionales que trae.

Por ello, creo que lo que él pretendía era que encontraran esos parámetros y manipular el valor con el que puede iniciar de la siguiente manera:

```js
function sumOfTen(){ 
    return [2,5,1,5,2,1].reduce( (a,b) => (a+b), -6); 

    // nótese que no se le está restando el 6
    // sino que se le está indicando el valor de inicio en -6
}
    
console.log(sumOfTen());
```

Comment: ¡Hola! es una buena solución pero no esta modificando el array solo cambia el valor del resultado no el array :(  . Según mi profesor se debe modificar el array pero dentro de la función no el inicial.

Comment: Creo que sigues sin entender.  Ese 6 que yo adiciono al final, hace parte de los parámetros de la función, o sea, hace parte de la función.  El array NO lo estoy modificando, es el mismo, te invito a que consultes toda la sintaxis de la función reduce, para que entiendas lo que significa ese -6 como parámetro.

**[Array.reduce()](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce)**

Comment: Si te entiendo, lo que tu quizás no entiendes es que SI necesito modificar el array pero dentro la función.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `forEach()` le restamos 1 a cada elemento del array dentro de la función, sin modificar el array que mandas como argumento...

```js
function sumOfTen(arr){
  arr.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    array[index] = element-1;
  });
  return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}

console.log(sumOfTen([2,5,1,5,2,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

listo encontré la solución, muchas gracias todos por su ayuda, aprendí varias cosas. :)

```
function sumOfTen(arr){
  arr.splice(2,2)
  return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}

console.log(sumOfTen([2,5,1,5,2,1]));
```

Comment: El problema es que no has explicado la lógica que debe seguir el código para devolver `10`... **¿por qué `10'**  y no `500` o un millón o `NaN`?. Si quieres que retorne `10` te podría decir que la mejor solución es esta: `function isTen (arr){ return 10; }` este es el código más idóneo para devolver `10`, un código sin lógica, claro está.

Comment: @A.Cedano El array devuelve 16, el profesor quiere que devuelva 10 sin modificar el array inicial. Debes modificar el array pero dentro de la función. ¿Por que 10? porque así me lo pidieron , aunque su suma de 16, me indican que devuelva 10

Comment: Con todo respeto para ti y para tu profesor, no le veo ni pies ni cabeza a eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que entendí es que debe modificar los valores del arreglo dentro de la función. Lo que dijo "sin modificar el array inicial" se debe referir a no modificar los argumentos. Igual está muy confuso el modo en que preguntó... Edit: Yuranis, la solución de restarle 6 no modifica el array, es lo mismo que colocar return 10, estás forzando el resultado

Comment: Encontré la solución, solo era utilizar el arr.splice(2,2) y listo . Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: @YuranisVillalba no olvides [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Para futuras preguntas, lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Variante: si el valor de la reducción actual es menor a 10 se le suma el elemento sino se le resta.

```js
function sumOfTen(arr){ 
    return arr.reduce( (a,b) => (a<10?a+b:a-b)); 
}
    
console.log(sumOfTen([2,5,1,5,2,1]));
```

---

Experimento con una [función generadora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/function*), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) y [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) que [devuelve todos los Subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773837/1423096) que suman 10. Se usa [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) para darle formato a los resultados.

```js
// Genera todos los subsets:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773837/1423096
function* subsets(array, offset = 0) {
  while (offset < array.length) {
    let first = array[offset++];
    for (let subset of subsets(array, offset)) {
      subset.push(first);
      yield subset;
    }
  }
  yield [];
}

// suma de cada uno de los subsets
function sumOfSubsets(arr) {
  let brr = [...subsets(arr)].filter(subset => {
    return subset.length // descartamos el subset vacío
  }).map(subset => {
    return (subset.join(' + ') + " = " + subset.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
  });
  return brr;
}

// suma de cada uno de los subsets con resultado = 10
function sumOfTen(arr) {
  let brr = [...subsets(arr)].filter(subset => {
    return (subset.length && subset.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) == 10)
  }).map(subset => {
    return (subset.join(' + ') + " = 10")
  });
  return brr;
}

let seq = [2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 1];

console.log(`sumOfTen([${seq.join()}])`);
console.log(sumOfTen(seq));

console.log(`sumOfSubsets([${seq.join()}])`);
console.log(sumOfSubsets(seq));
```

Comment: ¡Hola! es una buena solución pero no esta modificando el array solo cambia el valor del resultado no el array :( . Según mi profesor se debe modificar el array pero dentro de la función, no el inicial.